# Distroless docker + sudo

Tags: docker, sudo

I have dissected Google's distroless images to see how they're built as I'd like to use them but my company wants to have images we have built ourselves.

It looks like Google build glibc, libssl, and openssl in their base images so I did the same. I added a statically linked busybox, curl, and sudo for testing purposes. However, when I login as my user sudo tells me that it is unable to read libraries that exist on the system. At first I thought it had to do with root's environment because setuid but passwd is also setuid and it works.

Here is some output:

```
Distroless  [gdanko@5bd77574a894]:~ $ ldd /usr/bin/sudo
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff5e728000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f4bf61a1000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f4bf5f6a000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4bf5d4c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4bf59b3000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4bf6621000)

Distroless  [gdanko@5bd77574a894]:~ $ ls -l /lib64/libutil.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            15 Oct  2 17:45 
/lib64/libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.25.so

Distroless  [gdanko@5bd77574a894]:~ $ ls -l /lib64/libcrypt.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            16 Oct  2 17:45 
/lib64/libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.25.so

Distroless  [gdanko@5bd77574a894]:~ $ ls -l /lib64/libpthread.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            18 Oct  2 17:45 
/lib64/libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.25.so

Distroless  [gdanko@5bd77574a894]:~ $ ls -l /lib64/libc.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Oct  2 17:45 
/lib64/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.25.so

Distroless  [gdanko@5bd77574a894]:~ $ sudo
sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libutil.so.1: cannot open 
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I su - root and execute sudo it works

```
Distroless  [gdanko@5bd77574a894]:~ $ su - root
Password: 
Distroless  [root@5bd77574a894]:~ # sudo
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] file ...
```

I was wondering if it was in how Google built glibc but I could not find anything glaring.

The other thing is, if I use Google's distroless base for my image and copy my sudo over, busybox works in the container. I have tried a number of different things trying to troubleshoot this but I am at a loss. Can anyone see something I may be missing??